# NuGet - This package has not been indexed yet. It will appear in search results and will be available for install/restore after indexing is completed

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have a NuGet package that I can't find when looking at available updates in Visual Studio. If I check the package online it is marked as `This package has not been indexed yet. It will appear in search results and will be available for install/restore after indexing is completed.`.

[image]

Can I update this package without using NuGet server? I have been waiting for 15 minutes and wan't to continue.

Comment: If you want to use NuGet with your own packages then you need to wait until its indexed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Download the `.nupkg` file from NuGet and place it in `Downloads` for example. After that run:

```
Install-Package HiQ.Repository.EntityFramework -Source "C:\Users\User\Downloads\"
```

Comment: Actually you can just type `Install-Package HiQ.Repository.EntityFramework -Version 1.43.0` after the package is published but not yet indexed, after receiving the published notification email.